# Gradle excluding module not working

Tags: gradle, birt

I am trying to use latest BIRT version and this was my dependency:

```
compile ('org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.6.0-20160607') {
  exclude(module:'org.apache.poi')
}
```

And was getting errors like this:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
Could not find any version that matches org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:[3.11.0,3.11.1).  
Versions that do not match:
     3.11.0.v20160603-1336
     3.10.100.v20150529-1857   Required by:
     :tangio:unspecified > org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342
     :tangio:unspecified > org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:1.6.0.v20160503-1608
```

I am not exactly sure what the error means and where it is getting the two different versions, so to avoid that I tried to force gradle to use a specific version.

so my current gradle dependency:

```
compile('org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.6.0-20160607') {
    exclude(module:'org.apache.poi')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', module: 'org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.osgi')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.common')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.jobs')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.registry')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.preferences')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.contenttype')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.expressions')
    exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.filesystem')
    transitive = false
    //compile group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', name: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime', version: '3.12.0.v20160606-1342'
}

compile ('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:3.6.0.v20160120-1756'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:3.6.100.v20160223-2218'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.contenttype:3.5.100.v20160418-1621'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:3.8.0.v20160509-1230'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.expressions:3.5.100.v20160418-1621'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:3.11.0.v20160603-1336'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:1.6.0.v20160503-1608'){
    force = true
}
compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.resources:3.11.0.v20160503-1608'){
    force = true
}
```

But still am getting same error. How can I force Gradle to include single version?

Comment: So you want to use all those `forced` versions?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following lines:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.jobs:3.8.0.v20160509-0411'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:3.6.0.v20160120-1756'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:3.6.100.v20160223-2218'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.contenttype:3.5.100.v20160418-1621'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:3.8.0.v20160509-1230'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.expressions:3.5.100.v20160418-1621'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:3.11.0.v20160603-1336'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:1.6.0.v20160503-1608'
    force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.resources:3.11.0.v20160503-1608'
  }
}
```

NOTE: I added extra line `force 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.jobs:3.8.0.v20160509-0411'`, since `./gradlew dependencies` would fail:

```
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:[3.11.0,3.11.1) -> 3.11.0.v20160603-1336
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.jobs:[3.8.0,3.8.1) FAILED
```

Now, `dependencies` closure looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.6.0-20160607') {
        exclude(module:'org.apache.poi')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', module: 'org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.osgi')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.common')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.jobs')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.registry')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.preferences')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.contenttype')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.expressions')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', module: 'org.eclipse.core.filesystem')
        transitive = false
        //compile group: 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps', name: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime', version: '3.12.0.v20160606-1342'
    }

    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:3.6.0.v20160120-1756')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:3.6.100.v20160223-2218')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.contenttype:3.5.100.v20160418-1621')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:3.8.0.v20160509-1230')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.expressions:3.5.100.v20160418-1621')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:3.11.0.v20160603-1336')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:1.6.0.v20160503-1608')
    compile('org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.resources:3.11.0.v20160503-1608')
}
```

Here is `./gradlew dependencies` output:

```
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
+--- com.google.guava:guava:22.0
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18
|    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
+--- org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.6.0-20160607
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.12.0.v20160606-1342
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:[3.11.0,3.11.1) -> 3.11.0.v20160603-1336
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.jobs:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-0411
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:[3.6.100,3.6.101) -> 3.6.100.v20160223-2218
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:[3.6.0,3.6.1) -> 3.6.0.v20160120-1756
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
|    \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.contenttype:[3.5.100,3.5.101) -> 3.5.100.v20160418-1621
|         +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:[3.6.0,3.6.1) -> 3.6.0.v20160120-1756 (*)
|         +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:[3.6.100,3.6.101) -> 3.6.100.v20160223-2218 (*)
|         \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:3.6.0.v20160120-1756 (*)
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:3.6.100.v20160223-2218 (*)
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.contenttype:3.5.100.v20160418-1621 (*)
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:3.8.0.v20160509-1230
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.expressions:3.5.100.v20160418-1621
|    \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:[3.12.0,3.12.1) -> 3.12.0.v20160606-1342 (*)
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:3.11.0.v20160603-1336
+--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:1.6.0.v20160503-1608
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.8.0,3.8.1) -> 3.8.0.v20160509-1230
|    +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:[3.6.100,3.6.101) -> 3.6.100.v20160223-2218 (*)
|    \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.osgi:[3.11.0,3.11.1) -> 3.11.0.v20160603-1336
\--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.resources:3.11.0.v20160503-1608
     +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.expressions:[3.5.100,3.5.101) -> 3.5.100.v20160418-1621 (*)
     +--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:[1.6.0,1.6.1) -> 1.6.0.v20160503-1608 (*)
     \--- org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:[3.12.0,3.12.1) -> 3.12.0.v20160606-1342 (*)
```

Comment: thank you can you please put your whole gradle file content on pastebin? and please try if ```gradle build``` works for you.

Comment: `./gradlew` and gradle is essentially equivalent thing if your installed gradle is same version as the gradle wrapper. This is my code, https://pastebin.com/xMX84kxH

Comment: Thanks, @chenrui. I am getting the class not found an exception. Any idea of which lib:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform